# Label has an unwanted ampersand and cent sign

Tags: extra

I'm trying to create a label and I copied it from another label's code. The new label is printing 2 extra unwanted characters side by side; an ampersand and a cent sign. I double checked that line of code in my original and new label and they match exactly, but the original label prints just fine, with no unwanted characters.

Comment: It sounds like you're creating a custom menu, and trying to display it with MicroFocus "Extra!", correct?  Q: What version of Extra! are you using, and how are you testing (displaying) it?  Q: Could you show us code?

Comment: I'm using Produce Pro and there is already a label created, so there is a way to copy the code from that label to help you create your new label and the code line that is displaying the cent sign and ampersand is at the end of the line. It's supposed to say "NET WEIGHT: 1200#" but instead has the cent and ampersand on the end. That line of code is: ^FO20,820^A0N,50^FB1200,1,0,C^FD